# show a specific value at x axis without break in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Context**

I want to show a specific value at x axis in ggplot2. It is `2.84` in the **Reproducible code**.

I found the answer at [How can I add specific value to x-axis in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47930912/11636376)

It very close to my need.

**Question**

Is there some way that do not need set `breaks` and `labels`  in `scale_x_continuous` to show a specific value at x axis.

Because I need to draw a large number of similar images, setting the `breaks` and `labels` for each image will be very tedious.

**Reproducibale code**

```
# make up some data
d <- data.frame(x = 6*runif(10) + 1,
                y = runif(10))

# generate break positions
breaks = c(seq(1, 7, by=0.5), 2.84)
# and labels
labels = as.character(breaks)

# plot
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 7), breaks = breaks, labels = labels,
                     name = "Number of treatments")
```

[image]

Comment: Is `geom_text()` or `geom_label()` okay? I think what you want is in fact to annotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automate this process by creating a wrapper round `scale_x_continuous` that inserts your break into a vector of `pretty` breaks:

```r
scale_x_fancy <- function(xval, ...) {
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = ~ sort(c(pretty(.x, 10), xval)), ...)
}
```

So now you just add the x value(s) where you want the extra break to appear:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_fancy(xval = 2.84, name = "Number of treatments")
```

[image]